# Reduce space between Sinput and Soutput

Tags: spacing, sweave, fancyvrb

I'm using Sweave in the book document class, and I'm getting really huge spacing between Sinput and Soutput evironments.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}


\begin{document}


...

\begin{boxedminipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> 3 + 3
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 6
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
> 2 * 4
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 8
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
> (369 - 1)/6
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 61.33333
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
\end{boxedminipage}

...
\end{document}
```

And the end result looks like this:

[image]

Any advice for how to reduce that spacing?

Comment: Does the code in the input get run by R, or is it purely part of your LaTeX document?  For example, would it be acceptable for these cases to put them all in a single environment, (either `Sinput` or `Soutput`) provided you could apply the correct formatting to distinguish the input from the output?

Comment: `Sweave` seems to rely on the [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package (see [this `Sweave.sty` source file](http://www.cepe.ethz.ch/education/NPecoHS2010/Sweave.sty)). So the more general question is: *How to remove the spacing between two (`fancyvrb`) `Verbatim` environments?*

Comment: @Alan Munn, the Schunk, Sinput and Soutput environments are all generated by R.

Comment: Ok. See my revised answer for a solution.

Answer (score 8):

Include the following code into your document after having loaded `Sweave`:

```
\newlength{\fancyvrbtopsep}
\newlength{\fancyvrbpartopsep}
\makeatletter
\FV@AddToHook{\FV@ListParameterHook}{\topsep=\fancyvrbtopsep\partopsep=\fancyvrbpartopsep}
\makeatother
```

Now you'll be able to controll the spacing around the `Sinput` and `Soutput` environments by using the following two lengths:

- `\fancyvrbtopsep`
- `\fancyvrbpartopsep`

Both act quite similar most of the time, more details can be found in the [`fancyvrb` documentation on page 46](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf#page=46).

To kill all extra spacing between the environments, use

```
\setlength{\fancyvrbtopsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fancyvrbpartopsep}{0pt}
```

[image: Output result]

If you want to reduce the spacing without removing it completely, set `\fancyvrbtopsep` or `\fancyvrbpartopsep` to the desired value, e.g. `\setlength{\fancyvrbtopsep}{3mm}`.

---

#### Explanation:

`Sweave.sty` is based on [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb), which uses a `list` to display its contents and to control margins and spacing. (Actually, it's a bit more complicated, as `fancyvrb` uses a mixture of rewritten parts of the `list` code in the LaTeX kernel and the original macro calls.) The appearance of lists can be controlled by `\topsep`, `\partopsep`, `\itemsep`, `\parsep`, ...

In this special case, only the values `\topsep` and `\partopsep` as described above are important. You cannot, however, simply set these values e.g. in the preamble as they are overwritten by the class-specific default values (stored in `\@listi`, `\@listii`, ...) when a new list is created.

Instead, you have to hook into the `fancyvrb` code after these changes have been made, which can be done by adding the necessary code to `\FV@ListParameterHook`.

Answer (score 5):

Sweave uses `fancyvrb` to format its code, so the fix requires changing the vertical space in the within that package. Since that is not a user-changeable parameter, we need to patch the `\FV@ListVSpace` command.  I've done this using the `etoolbox` package, which provides a number of cool tools for patching commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\FV@ListVSpace}{\@topsepadd\topsep}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedminipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> 3 + 3
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 6
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
> 2 * 4
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 8
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
> (369 - 1)/6
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 61.33333
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
\end{boxedminipage}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I guess that'll work for the code I gave above, but that was automatically generated by Sweave in R, so the original multiple verbatim environments are kind of non-negotiable.

Comment: @JoFrhwld Ok.  I've completely revised my answer.  This should work now with the auto-generated code.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\FV@ListVSpace}{\@topsepadd\topsep}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedminipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> 3 + 3
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 6
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
> 2 * 4
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 8
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
> (369 - 1)/6
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 61.33333
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
\end{boxedminipage}
```